# How to safely execute unknown Javascript code in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval

I need to run code supplied by an unknown source which validates or sorts something.

How can I do this safely in Node.js?

Python has [RestrictedPython](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/RestrictedPython), anything similar?

There is also [ADsafe](http://www.adsafe.org/) for the browser, but is it usable in Node.js?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Node has an excellent tool for this, the [node.vm](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/vm.html). Basically you can run a script in its own context, effectively sandboxing it.

Of course, since Node runs on a single thread, a harmful script can always shut down your server just by doing:

```
while (true) {;}
```

To be completely safe, you need to spawn a new process and use message passing for communication.